# Please help with this issue, I am new to Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

Media change: please insert the disc labeled
'Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS *Jammy Jellyfish* - Release amd64 (20240220)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. We need me context. [Edit your question and add the following](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506939/edit): what were you trying to do? Which straps did you follow? What exactly did you do for the "media change"? Why did you change the media?